# Finding out if the relationship is linear based on binary values and do ANCOVA analysis

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R and wanted to implement some of the concepts I have learnt in R programming. I have a data set where I have different binary values (1 and 0) for different columns which are basically independent variables while I have dependent variable with some values. I have a data set like this:

```
   Salary(Dependent)     Qualification(independent)     Married (Independent)
         1000                          1                       0 
         1100                           0                      1
         1200                           1                      1 
         1300                           0                      0
         1400                           1                      0
         1500                           0                      1
```

First I would like to determine if the relationship is linear and then do ANCOVA analysis to see if there are any interaction effects on independent variable.

Comment: This might be better off on stats.stackexchange.com . But before moving it there, think about what it means for a relationship to be "linear" across a binary predictor. What other relationship could you observe, given that there are only ever going to be 2 values of the predictor? Think about exactly what analysis you want to do and try it out.

Comment: @Marius Thank You for your suggestion ! I will do that as well.